# Implied volatility from local volatility versus market implied volatility

Tags: implied-volatility, calibration, local-volatility

Does the local volatility flattens the (existing not forward) skew faster than what we observed in the implied volatility surface?

The process is:

1. Get market implied volatilities
2. Fit a IV model (i.e. SVI)
3. Using IVs and Dupire equation obtain LV, price options and imply IV from those options.

What would you observe?
Assuming that 1 matches close 2, and 3 is derived using Dupire equation from 2, would you expect to have 3 matching very closely 1 (or 2)?

Comment: What options do you price with LV in point3? Generally, Local volatility (LV) models can fit the vanilla option prices perfectly for a given maturity. Since most LV implementations will calibrate to the vol surface (point 2), you should end up with the exact same result and IV between 2 and 3 (ignoring calibration errors).

Comment: Just a plain empirical analysis on EU vanilla options. I was wondering whether the 2nd order der. wrt to K for larger T will flatten the smile faster than its supposed to.
So avoiding calibration errors as you note and numerical discretisation errors one should expect that the resulting IV (by inverting the EU vanilla price to get the IV) should exactly match the market IV (or more correctly the SVI used to get the LV). Thank you very much